# CKEditor not loading

Tags: ckeditor

I have the following problem

I have a page with a content div where pages are loaded in via AJAX and menu items called STEP 1 , STEP 2 etc

NOw everytime I click on a step a new page is being loaded in the content div. One of the pages contains CKEditor

When clicking on the link that contains CKEditor, CKEditor loads perfectly, when I click on the link again, the spcae where CKEditor is is blank, not loading, so I need to hard refresh the page and click on the link again, then ck editor is displaying again. Any advice will be highly apprciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solved my problem

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['editor1']) {

  CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].destroy();

}
```

Comment: Accept this as the answer?